# AWS Lambda Function: Unzipped size must be smaller than 262144000 bytes

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to create an API for machile learning. For that, I'm using AWS, GitHub and a python project. I created a GitHub Action that saves, in a zip, all the site-packages (in the venv) and the ML models and scripts to run the API. This Action, also add this zip to a S3 Bucket and launch a Lambda function, that imports the zip previously placed in S3.

My problem is: the zip file is too large for lambda.

```
Unzipped size must be smaller than 262144000 bytes
```

How can I fix this? IS there a better alternative?

PS.: I need to have the gitub connected to the API

Comment: Try to check what is bundled in the zip, try to reduce the size - if you cannot reduce the size you cannot use lambda.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your deployment package is too big. Double check if you really need all the software / libraries you've zipped.

From the docs:

> There is a hard limit of 50MB for compressed deployment package with AWS Lambda and an uncompressed AWS Lambda hard limit of 250MB.

Note that you have a region wide soft limit of 75GB for all AWS Lambda functions that have been deployed.

Otherwise, you have the following options:

- [Container images](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/images-create.html)
- [Layers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html)
- Using other AWS services e.g. ECS

A hacky way:

If you really need to ship all the dependencies along with your AWS Lambda, you might want to put a large binary or dependency package into an S3 bucket. Then, make your Lambda fetch these.

Comment: Can you explain the hacky way again please? Am I not doing that? I already have the zip into the s3

Comment: The hacky way means you pull the files / dependencies programmatically from S3. In other words, you're pulling in a file from AWS S3 which is too large to be included in our AWS Lambda deployment package.

Comment: How does using layers bypass this limit?

Comment: Yeah it doesn't.